# Putting your HTML files in the /public directory?

Tags: html, templating

Is there anything inherently wrong with putting HTML files in the internet-facing public folder?

Is there security issues with this approach? Can't you just view source anyways?

Do we have our views outside the public folder purely for templating purposes?

I'd appreciate your thoughts on this.

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: If you have your files on a publicly accessible path and don't have some type of directory-based authentication setup (like Basic Authentication), then there is no security. You put them there so browsers can access them without you needing to create a file that gets the file and sends it to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML files are usually put in the public directory. The directory is named differently in different setups. Some people name it `public_html`. Some name it just `public`. Some name it `www`. There is nothing wrong with putting the HTML files there.

You should just make sure that nobody other than you has write permissions on the folder as a general security measure. If you are serving CGI scripts, or if you have sensitive data (say a configuration file for your website which users are not supposed to see), they should be kept outside the public directory.

Answer (score 4):

If you want them to be public there is no problem with putting them in the public folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular advantage or disadvantage wrt security with putting the files in your public folder.

Answer (score 1):

Are they viewable HTML files or stubs/templates? If they're templates, the visitor need not see them.